# Change pin's image (on map) when it loses focus

Tags: android, focus, android-mapview, marker, osmdroid

I have a map with some markers.
Markers are defined in a class that extends `ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>`.
On the onTap() I change  marker's image.

I want to change the marker image also when it loses focus.

I've tried

```
   @Override
    public void setOnFocusChangeListener(OnFocusChangeListener l) {
        Drawable onTapMarker = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_blue);
        currentItem.setMarker(onTapMarker);
        super.setOnFocusChangeListener(l);
    }
```

but is never fired.
 How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you use `setOnFocusChangeListener`. This method is designed to be called directly by you and to set a listener callback object that will receive events when the focus changed. So instead you would call

```
mItemizedOverlay.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChanged(ItemizedOverlay<?> overlay, OverlayItem newFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

and do your work in onFocusChanged.

But there is a better way to change the icon when it receives/loses focus. You can create a StateListDrawable that has its `OverlayItem.ITEM_STATE_FOCUSED_MASK` state set to the drawable you want to use for when your item is focused. You can create one programmatically

```
StateListDrawable d = new StateListDrawable();
d.addState(new int[]{OverlayItem.ITEM_STATE_FOCUSED_MASK}, mFocusedDrawable);
d.addState(new int[]{}, mDefaultDrawable);
```

and then use that as your Item's icon.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I had to pass "new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed}" to addState to get it working